# how could i include all the keys in the username? even if they're multipul? for example, if the username is "ad" and it's not include at the library

Tags: python

```
user_guess = input("Guess a letter: ")

if len(user_guess) > 1 and user_guess in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ':
    print("E1")
elif user_guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ':
    print("E2")
elif(len(user_guess) > 1) and (user_guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'):
    print("E3")
else:
    print(user_guess.lower())
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where is the username in the code example? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Are you trying to check the string is all letters? That would just be `user_guess.isalpha()`

Comment: i want to get a "E1" answer for a username that include more then one character

Comment: and i want to gat a "E2" answer for username that isn't in the English alphabet

Comment: and a "E3" answer for both of the option

Comment: @IdanAbramovich By "username" do you mean `user_guess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if user_guess in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

This is only true if `user_guess` is not a substring of the entire alphabet (in that order). I think this isn't what you want. My guess is that you want to make sure that `user_guess` is only made up of alphabetic characters.

You can do this yourself, by checking each character of `user_guess`.

Or you can just do

```
if user_guess.isalpha()
```